# How do I display a DOMElement?

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm using [readability](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~keyvan-k1m/fivefilters/content-only/annotate/head:/readability.php)'s code to extract HTML from a web page. How do I display it on a page?

```
$content = grabArticle($webpage);
echo $content;

ERROR => Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string...
```

Comment: What would you like to display? The content of the element? The tag name? The HTML including the element?

Answer (score 9):

Marc B's answer got me on the right track, but I had a similar need and this was the code I landed on:

```
$newdoc = new DOMDocument;
$node = $newdoc->importNode($node, true);
$newdoc->appendChild($node);
$html = $newdoc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$content = grabArticle($webpage);

$newdoc = new DOM;
$newdoc->importNode($content);

$html = $newdoc->saveHTML();
```

That'll creat a new complete HTML document based on the node you extracted in grabArticle. If you're inserting that into another HTML page, you'll need to strip off the leading/trailing tags that DOM inserts.

Answer (score 6):

Yes the answer that Mike gave is correct.  Here is a simple example that takes the

nodes found and creates a new document.

```
$newdoc = new DOMDocument;
$nodes = $oldoc->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    $newnode = $newdoc->importNode($node, true);
    $newdoc->appendChild($newnode);
}
//print the new html
$html = $newdoc->saveHTML();
```