# Find all occurences of an HTML tag in PHP

Tags: php, html

How would I be able to find all occurrences of an html tag? For example, if my string was...

```
<h1>Images</h1>
<img src="img/bird.jpg">
<p>Hello world</p>
<img src="img/beach.jpg" alt="test" class="picture">
```

And If I wanted to make a list of all IMG tags, it would come out like this:

```
<img src="img/bird.jpg">
<img src="img/beach.jpg" alt="test" class="picture">
```

How would you guys do this?

Comment: you can use a DOM for this

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: Pretty similar to this question yesterday, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020171/regular-expression-to-find-all-src-attribute-of-html-img-element-only-folder/32020330#32020330 could merge that with this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818759/how-do-i-display-a-domelement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the simple html dom library from here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Here's how you find find all `img` tags:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = str_get_html('<h1>Images</h1>
<img src="img/bird.jpg">

<p>Hello world</p>
<img src="img/beach.jpg" alt="test" class="picture">');

foreach($html->find('img') as $img) {
    print $img->outertext . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: This would probably be the easiest option. However, is there a way to do it without a library?

Comment: yep, see the comment by @FuzzyTree

Comment: After using this, I'm going to go with this one. Although if you don't want to go through the trouble of installing, @FuzzyTree's comment would be the best option.